# Can't assess grub on dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 without shutting down windows and powering on again

Tags: dual-boot

I have a hp envy dv6 PC on which I just dual booted Ubuntu 12.04LTS with the pre-installed windows 8. problem now is that I can't assess grub and thus boot ubuntu without having to shut down windows, start up,  and then choose the option to boot from notebook hard drive. I have enabled legacy boot and disabled secure boot in Bios settings.

NB: I am new to Ubuntu and have minimal programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is the absolute normal behaviour you expect when dual-booting. Your computer will only be able to run a single operating system at the time.

Therefore whenever you change your operating system from Windows to Ubuntu or *vice versa* you will have to reboot. The first boot device then has to be the drive where you had put the boot-loader Grub. You may have to change the boot order in BIOS to always boot from the drive Grub sits on.

In case you need both operating systems running at the sane time there is no other choice than putting one of them into a virtual machine installed in the other OS.